# Unsatisfied link error in an OSGI jar with an aar dependency that includes native libraries

Tags: android, jar, osgi, shared-libraries, aar

I am trying to build an **OSGI jar** using maven which depends on an aar which includes native libraries.

Instead of adding the aar as a dependency, I extracted the classes.jar and added that as a dependency and then added the shared libs in a libs/ directory at the root of the jar.

The final structure of the jar looks like this.

```
/org/MyClasses
/org/LibClasses (from aar)
/libs/armeabi-v7a/allNativeFiles (from aar)
/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

When making a call to a method provided by the LibClasses it calls ***System.loadLibrary('some_so_file')*** to load one of the **.so** files but the call is throwing an unsatisfied link error because it cannot find the file at the path.

Here's the exception :

> 07-22 06:31:30.112: E/art(2537):
>   dlopen("/data/data/org.ambientdynamix.core/files/felix/felix-cache/bundle14/version0.0/bundle.jar-lib/0/libs/armeabi-v7a/liboc_logger.so",
>   RTLD_LAZY) failed: dlopen failed: could not load library
>   "libgnustl_shared.so" needed by "liboc_logger.so"; caused by library
>   "libgnustl_shared.so" not found

Android is looking for the .so file at ...*/bundle.jar-lib/0/libs/armeabi-v7a* when the file is at ...*/bundle.jar/libs/armeabi-v7a*

Plugin configuration from the POM :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.7</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <!-- configure plugin to generate MANIFEST.MF -->
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>bundle-manifest</id>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>manifest</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <!-- configure plugin to support jar packaging -->
        <supportedProjectTypes>
            <supportedProjectType>jar</supportedProjectType>
        </supportedProjectTypes>
        <instructions>
            <Export-Package>
                org.ambientdynamix.contextplugins.iotivity
            </Export-Package>
            <Bundle-NativeCode>libs/armeabi-v7a/libca-interface.so ;
                libs/armeabi-v7a/libconnectivity_abstraction.so ; libs/armeabi-v7a/libgnustl_shared.so
                ;libs/armeabi-v7a/liboc.so ;libs/armeabi-v7a/liboc_logger.so
                ;libs/armeabi-v7a/libocstack-jni.so ;libs/armeabi-v7a/liboctbstack.so ;
                osname=Linux;
                processor=arm_le
            </Bundle-NativeCode>
            <Import-Package>org.ambientdynamix.api.application,
                org.ambientdynamix.api.contextplugin,
                org.ambientdynamix.api.contextplugin.security
            </Import-Package>
            <Bundle-ClassPath>
                .
            </Bundle-ClassPath>
            <Bundle-Activator/>

            <Include-Resource>native=src/main/resources/libs</Include-Resource>

            <DynamicImport-Package>*</DynamicImport-Package>
            <Bundle-SymbolicName>org.ambientdynamix.contextplugins.iotivity</Bundle-SymbolicName>
        </instructions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Any possible way to fix this ?

Comment: Does your bundle have a Bundle-NativeCode header in the manifest?

Comment: Yeah. The native libs are being packed in the jar.

Comment: That's not what I asked. Putting the libs in the jar is necessary but you also need a Bundle-NativeCode header in the bundle's manifest so the framework can return the proper lib for the System.loadLibrary call.

Comment: Yep, I do have the Bundle-NativeCode header in the Manifest. Updated the configuration for the maven-bundle-plugin in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you have multilple libs that have inter-dependencies. Typically, one lib is the JNI code that is referenced in your Java code via a System.loadLibrary call. Then that lib will reference another lib. The issue is that the VM process has no idea how to find those other libs because they are in a folder (e.g. /data/data/org.ambientdynamix.core/files/felix/felix-cache/bundle14/version0.0/bundle.jar-lib/0/libs/) which the VM process does not know of and is not on LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

A possible solution to this is for your java code to call System.loadLibrary on each of the libs but you have to do this in the right order. First you load the libs which do not depend on any of the other libs, then the libs which depend upon already loaded libs and then finally the JNI lib. This way each lib's dependencies are already loaded in the VM process for linking to the currently loading lib.

This is not a pretty solution since you have many libs to load and hopefully there are no cycles in the dependency graph.

Comment: Thanks so much! Just in case if anyone faces this issue in future, I used the `readelf -d` command to find the dependencies of each of the .so libs and then used System.loadLibrary to load these in order in my java code before the referenced library does it on it's own.